# Зачем нужны "пустые" методы в CBV django?

Tags: python, django

На пример метод get_ordering из BaseListView (код из документации):

```
class MyList(BaseListView):
    ordering = None

    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.ordering
```

Атрибут ordering не приватный даже, а в методах класса его можно получить просто через self.ordering.

Пока что я в этом вижу просто две лишние строчки кода и бесполезное неявное усложнение. Но ведь должен быть в этом какой-то смысл?

Comment: Очевидно, внутри метода можно написать какой-нибудь сложный алгоритм вычисления значения, который не получится сделать с обычным атрибутом. Если вам сложный алгоритм не нужен, то и метод писать не требуется, по умолчанию и так используется self.ordering

Comment: @andreymal если нужен метод для вычисления значения, то можно его и определить с ноля, зачем для этого пустой метод?

Comment: Он и не нужен, никто не заставляет его писать если не надо

Comment: @andreymal я о том, что даже если нужен, то можно объявить свой метод и не переопределять пустой родительский.

Comment: Django обращается именно к методу get_ordering, так что если создадите какой-то другой метод, он будет просто проигнорирован

Comment: @andreymal понимаю. Вопрос в том, почему это реализовано Django именно так. А не просто через получение self.ordering, который можно изменить собственным методом перед обращением к нему в Django. Или в другом существующем методе изменить, на пример в get_queryset(), что выглядит вполне логично.